# LinqToXml: parsing and formatting

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following xml:

```
<Places Count='50'>
<Place ID='1' Row='1' Place='1' Status='10' Fragment='0'></Place>
<Place ID='2' Row='1' Place='2' Status='10' Fragment='0'></Place>
<Place ID='3' Row='1' Place='3' Status='10' Fragment='0'></Place>
<Place ID='4' Row='1' Place='4' Status='10' Fragment='0'></Place>
//other tags
</Places>
```

This is my method:

```
public static List<string> ParseFreePlace(string response, string level)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response)) return new List<string>();

   return XDocument.Parse(response).Descendants("Place")
         .Select(element => (string) element.Attribute("Row")).ToList();
}
```

I want to get `List<string>` with the following content:

```
r=1;p=1;f=0;l=54; // 0 element in the List
r=1;p=2;f=0;l=54; // 1 element in the List
r=1;p=3;f=0;l=54; // 2 element in the List
r=1;p=4;f=0;l=54; // 3 element in the List
```

The `l` in the content is `level` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
public static List<string> ParseFreePlace(string response, string level)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response)) return new List<string>();

   return 
        XDocument.Parse(response)
                 .Descendants("Place")
                 .Select(e =>
                    String.Format("r={0};p={1};f={2};l={3};",
                                   e.Attribute("Row").Value,
                                   e.Attribute("Place").Value,
                                   e.Attribute("Fragment").Value,
                                   level)
                 ).ToList();
}
```

When called like this (assuming `input` is the XML string):

```
var lines = ParseFreePlace(input, "54");
foreach (var line in lines) Console.WriteLine(line);
```

It returns this for me:

```
r=1;p=1;f=0;l=54;
r=1;p=2;f=0;l=54;
r=1;p=3;f=0;l=54;
r=1;p=4;f=0;l=54;
```

Comment: +1 You have forgotten the trailing semicolon, but other than that it looks good.

Comment: It is still missing from the sample output :)

Comment: Always the case isn't it. Done for completeness.